# Translating column headings in Hungarian marriage register (from Slovakia)?

Tags: marriage-records, hungary

Can anyone tell me the language used and/or translation to English of the Column headings in this Slovak Marriage register:

[image]
 Additional Info: for those interested here is the [Link](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:9Q97-Y39F-LPW?i=9&wc=9P3F-16V%3A107654301%2C111322501%2C111393001%2C145814501&cc=1554443), while some of the column headings are obvious, others are not. For example columns 7 and beyond may provide names of parents or sponsors (or wedding party members???)

Additional Info: For those that are interested - these "registers" are not the **original** parish registers, but rather the aggregation of original parish or synagogue records that were copied into the books by the state archivists, resulting in the images here. [see here](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Slovakia_Church_Records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGISTER OF MARRIAGES

- Consecutive number
- Year, month, and day of
  wedding
- The couple's

  - sur- and given name and civil status, along with the sur- and given name and civil status of the parents
  - birthplace and residence, street and house-number
  - religion
  - age
  - status

    - single
    - widow, widower
- Sur- and given name, civil status and religion of witnesses
- Sur- and given name and office of the officiant
- Were they announced; exempted from announcement or other obstacle
- Observations

Answer (score 8):

The language of the text is Hungarian. Mainly using an [online translator and dictionary](https://de.magyarnemet.hu) and the [word list linked by @ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/translating-column-headings-in-slovak-marriage-register#comment23249_15458), I came up with the following:

- Hazasultak: marriage
- A jegyesek: the bridal pair (i.e. bride and groom)
- Sorszám: (registration) number
- Esküvési év, hónap és nap: wedding year, month and day
- vezeték- és keresztneve: family name and given name
- polgári állása: occupation
- valamint a szülöknek...: as well as the parents'... [names and occupation]
- születés- és lakhelye: place of birth and place of living
- utcza s házszám: street and house number
- vallása: religion
- kora: age(s)

Utcza instead of utca and kora instead of kor don't seem to match common modern spelling, but the meaning is rather clear from the context provided.

Comment: Cz versus c is old-style versus modern spelling. (The changeover is roughly WWI.) *Kor* versus *kora* is nominative versus "of". (Hungarian does possessives backwards: the word that changes is the thing owned, not the owner.)